# ClassCastException using ByteBuffer as key for ChronicleMap

Tags: chronicle-map

I tried a very simple example where I try to write int -> ByteBuffer and reuse the array while reading the values from the map.

```java
    try (ChronicleMap<Integer, ByteBuffer> map = ChronicleMap
                    .of(Integer.class, ByteBuffer.class)
                    .entries(1)
                    .averageValueSize(30)
                    .createPersistedTo(new File("e:/temp/test.obj"))) {

                byte[] out = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3};         
                map.put(1, ByteBuffer.wrap(out)); // ClassCastException

                ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(30);
                ByteBuffer in = map.getUsing(1, buff); // hoping that 'ByteBuffer in'
                                                       // is redundant
    }
```

Unfortunately I get an unexpected `ClassCastException`, because Chronicle expected a `byte[]`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ChronicleMap{name=null, file=E:\temp\test.obj, identityHashCode=809762318}: Value must be a [B but was a class java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.checkValue(VanillaChronicleMap.java:190)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.put(VanillaChronicleMap.java:707)
    at test.SerTest.main(SerTest.java:28)
```

What am I doing wrong? Trying with `byte[]` worked, but `getUsing()` did not use my input array, that remained empty.

Comment: I apologize for the first version of the code,  I copy/pasted from a bigger example...

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report to https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/issues